# Use Lagrange Remainder Theorem to Prove Inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm supposed to use [Lagrange Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html) to prove that

$$1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} < \sqrt{1+x} < 1 + \frac{x}{2} \text{ } \text{ if } x>0$$

Obviously, the left and right hand sides look like Taylor series, but how would you do this using [Lagrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder), it isn't obviously intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: I've added links to mathworld and wikipedia, I hope you don't mind. (This might be useful, since not everybody must know the theorem or someone might know it, but not under this name.)

Answer (score 4):

For the RHS inequality you can even use Mean Value Theorem (which, of course, is a special case of Taylor theorem - where the reminder term contains first derivative).

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$. Then the theorem gives that there exists some $\theta \in (0,x)$ such that
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{\sqrt{1+x} - 1}{x} = f'(\theta) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1+\theta}}.
$$
Hence $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{1+\theta}} < 1 + \frac{x}{2}$ since $x > 0$. Observe that, of course, $\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{1+\theta}}$ is the reminder term in the Taylor theorem.

For the LHS by Taylor theorem you get that there exists $\theta \in (0,x)$ such that
$$
\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} x - \frac{1}{8} x^2 + \frac{1}{16} (1 + \theta)^{-5/2} x^3.
$$
The reminder term is positive for $x > 0$, which proves the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let $f(x)= \sqrt{1+x}$ and let $T_n$ be the nth degree Taylor Polynomial.

Then $R_n(x) = f(x)-T_n(x)$.

Now, what happens if you can prove that some $R_n(x)$ is positive or negative?